# Get a list of apps in a salesforce Organization

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, app, console

We can get the list of items in the Force.com app menu or App Launcher from the 'AppMenuItem' sobject. This cotains a field 'ApplicationId'. If this is the Id of the application for the item in Force.com, there might be an sobject which contains a row with id as this value. My purpose is to get the list of apps installed from appexchange or created in a salesforce organization. The records in 'AppMenuItem' sobject doesn't contain any field indicating the category of app, for example, Standard or Custom or Console. The value of 'Type' field indicates if the app is a connected or ServiceProvider or TabSet app. 
There is another sobject 'PackageLicense' represents licenses for installed managed packages. This sobject also doesn't have enough details.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can query on PackageLicense to know all the packages from your org.

> PackageLicense
>
> Represents a license for an installed managed package.  This object is
>   available in API version 31.0 and later.

```
SELECT  Id, AllowedLicenses, NamespacePrefix, Status, CreatedDate,ExpirationDate,
IsProvisioned,LastModifiedDate 
FROM PackageLicense
```